# Automatically prevent the title "Cannot read property 'X' of undefined" from being asked

Tags: feature-request, title

I would like the Stack Overflow website to block users from asking questions with the title "cannot read property 'X' of undefined" until they **change** the title. These questions are predominantly tagged "JavaScript" and related tags.

It's a poor quality title that often reflects a poor quality question, but they appear in my question feed every few minutes.

A quick Google search "site:stackoverflow.com 'cannot read' 'of undefined'" shows 170,000 results, and if you browse a few dozen pages of the results almost all of the links are for question titles.

From a moderation perspective it seems like this could easily be fixed by just blocking this title from future questions.

Comment: You'll just get the [prolbem issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110789/remove-blacklist-filter-for-problem) i.e. deliberate misspelling in order to get past the "stupid question block"

Comment: Fun fact: [the most common unreadable property is '0'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22cannot+read+property+%270%27+of+undefined%22).

Answer (score 13):

We *can* block such titles, but folks are gonna post the questions anyway - and probably not with more descriptive titles. The efficacy of such a block is gonna depend heavily on our ability to provide useful guidance to the folks writing them.

A bit of background for readers who may not be familiar with JavaScript: this is fundamentally equivalent to a null pointer deference exception (segfault, NullReferenceException, etc) in other languages. To see it in action, open your browser's console and type: `var foo; foo.baz;` then hit enter. As with most such errors, the root cause is usually far removed from the location of the error itself: faulty logic, improper library initialization, configuration, earlier failures, etc. are all likely possibilities: diagnosing the cause thus requires detailed information on either the code being debugged, the configuration of the program, the specific version(s) of the libraries being used, or all of the preceding.

That makes the presence of such titles an opportune time to provide a bit of advice on debugging to the author, as well as hints on which bits of information they'll need to include if they want help. Let's try & put together a succinct little guide for folks in this situation, & then test it in action!

#### See also:

- [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)
- [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)
- [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Same problem in the PHP language, `Notice: Undefined` -  [variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12778634#12778634), [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770836#12770836), [offset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21793407/3933332)

Comment: My windmills are ["object reference not set to an instance of an object"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22object+reference+not+set+to+an+instance+of+an+object%22)